# A word that describes someone who doesn't have a home/place to belong

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to describe a character that doesn't fit in anywhere despite giving off the appearance that they do.

Comment: There are a lot of [good synonyms of 'homeless'](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/homeless?s=t) that might work for you. But don't get hung up on using exactly a single word. many times it is better composition to use more words, than to shoehorn it into some single word that doesn't get the nuance you want. "doesn't fit in anywhere" may be exactly the feeling you want to get across.

Comment: Synonyms of 'outsider'?

Comment: @user121863 Yes, I realize that but you get the word/phrase you want by looking at all avenues, both literal and metaphorical. 'doesn't have a home' is not identical to 'homeless' is not identical to 'unattached' is not identical to 'sui generis' etc etc etc but following those connections may get what the OP wants.

Comment: Thanks @Mitch and Edwin Ashworth! I I ended up using a phrase instead as Mitch suggested.